# How do I distinguish Simplified and Traditional Chinese in C#?

Tags: .net, localization, internationalization, cjk, iso

My app has been translated to a number of languages, including French, Traditional Chinese, and Simplified Chinese. Now, when the app first launches, I'd like to automatically select the correct translation based on the user locale.

For French, evaluating the `TwoLettersIsoLanguageName` property of the `InstalledUiCulture` worked well, but for Chinese ISO codes are not sufficient. I thought of resorting to the `Name` property, which separates `zh-Hans` and `zh-Hant`, but that breaks French, since it gives `fr-FR` on certain systems, and `fr-CA` on others, for example.

Is there a simple way to get the current culture's two-letter language code if it's not chinese, and otherwise get `zh-Hans`/`zh-Hant`?

I'm searching for an elegant solution ; I've of course thought of parsing the culture's `Name` property and making a special case for chinese, but that's not really pretty :/

**In short, I think I'm searching for a way to retrieve a "neutral" culture from the current culture: from `fr-Fr` get `fr`, from `zh-TW` get `zh-Hant`, and from `zh-CN` get `zh-Hans`. Ideas?**

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using satellite assemblies?

Comment: Because I'm fixing on a rather old codebase :/

Comment: Don't forget Norwegian and Portuguese, for which there are also multiple dialects. And what happens if your company decides to create a special Canadian-French translation?

Comment: @RaymondChen: That's right. In that case I'll load the specific translation.

Comment: Then the question isn't really "I want a function that returns the subculture if the subculture is Chinese, but the neutral culture otherwise." It's "I want a function that returns the subculture if I have a translation for that subculture, and the neutral culture otherwise." And there is naturally no built-in OS function for this, since the OS doesn't know what languages you've been translated into.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Not really. I just have to check if I have a translation for the current specific culture. If I don't, I need to retrieve the corresponding neutral culture, and that's what the question was about. `Parent` works perfectly for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent.aspx) property of [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) class is what you are looking for.
It seems it was supported from the very beginning.

BTW. In case of translations, you should use [CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture.aspx) rather than [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) (the latter is meant for formatting) or InstalledUiCulture, which is Operating System language version and not necessary user preference.

Comment: Great, thanks! Side note for people finding this solution in the future: using the `IsNeutral` property first permits to make sure that you're not taking the parent of an already-neutral culture. Also worthy of mention: `InvariantCulture.Parent == InvariantCulture`